# Vendor code 17002 to connect to SQLDeveloper

Tags: database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to connect to a database using SQLDeveloper and I get the following error:

```
An Error was Encountered performing The requested operation:

IO Error: Conection reset

Vendor code 17002.
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Restart your SQLDeveloper. That works for me

Answer (score 25):

Listed are the steps that could rectify the error:

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `services.msc` and strike <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Find all services starting with `ora` start these services and wait!!
4. When your server specific service is initialized (in my case it was `orcl`)
5. Now run `mysql` or whatever you are using and start coding.P

Comment: Turn off your CAPS LOCK at first.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem for me.

Comment: In my system there is no service starting with 'ora'. Any ideas ?

Comment: what about linux ?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered same problem with ORACLE 11G express on Windows.
After a long time waiting I got the same error message.

My solution is to **make sure the hostname in tnsnames.ora (usually it's not "localhost") and the default hostname in sql developer(usually it's "localhost") same**. You can either do this by changing it in the tnsnames.ora, or filling up the same in the sql developer.

Oh, of course you need to reboot all the oracle services (just to be safe).

Hope it helps.

---

I came across the similar problem again on another machine, but this time above solution doesn't work.
After some trying, I found restarting all the oracle related services can fix the problem. Originally when the installation is done, connection can be made. Somehow after several reboot of computer, there is problem.
I change all the oracle services with start time as auto. And once I could not connect, I restart them all over again (the core service should be restarted at last order), and works fine.

Some article says it might be due to the MTS problem. Microsoft's problem. Maybe!

Comment: There are a few issues. First, according my experiencies, don't install Oracle on Windows. Oracle has been first dedicated for Unix (Solaris, VMS)/Linux platform. Second, after installation on Windows you MUST to do minimally two restarts of System to be sure, that services works properly. I have no explanation, but it is truth for years and many installations. Third, if you want use DB remotely (of course mostly we want), we must setup properly Listener  in sqlnet.ora, listener.ora, tnsnames.ora. Rather than 'localhost' or DNS name use exact IP address of host server, where is DB installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem. I had start my Oracle TNS Listener, then it works normally again.

See [LISTENER: TNS-12545 ... No such file or directory](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2296782).

Answer (score -5):

In your case the "Vendor code 17002" is the equivalent of the ORA-12541 error:  It's most likely that your listener is down, or has an improper port or service name.  From the docs:

```
ORA-12541: TNS no listener
```

Cause: Listener for the source repository has not been started.

Action: Start the Listener on the machine where the source repository resides.

Comment: verbatim from [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_developer_vendor_error_17002.htm) without attribution or any additional value to the answer